# Users do not have access rights to the site randomly

Tags: active-directory, authentication, sync

I meet a problem with some users.

They are in a active directory group which is in a Sharepoint group. They cannot randomly connect to sharepoint site ("sorry this site hasn't been shared with you").

This is a Sharepoint online tenant with directory synchronisation.

Clear cache browser seems to allow user to connect so I think there is a problem with the token cache (or a problem with dirsync ?)

If someone has a solution...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you remove this AD group from SP Online and do a synchronization. And you might re-add it in SP Online site. It should work, sometimes we also have the problems about synchronization.

Comment: The site is in production and active directory groups are used everywhere to give permissions ... So I think there is a big impact to remove ad groups... The isn't another solution ?

Comment: I mean you just remove your AD group from SP group and do a synchronization in a free time, is this possible?

Comment: it's not because sometimes security groups are used to give permissions instead of sharepoint group